# JAXB javaType customization on xs:integer produces @XmlElement with "type=String.class"

Tags: java, jaxb2, xjc

When generating Java beans from a XSD with XJC, I need to map `xs:integer` to `Integer` rather than `BigInteger`. I added a `javaType` tag to my JAXB customization file (as said in many answers from this site), and it worked fine.

But in the generated code I noticed that **the `@XmlElement` tag now has a `type=String.class` parameter**.

So now I wonder, why `String`?
Is it because the parse and print methods are converting from/to string objects?

I tried with `xjc:javaType` instead of `jaxb:javaType`, allowing me to replace the generated `Adapter1<String, Integer>` with a custom `MyAdapter<BigInteger, Integer>`, but exactly the same thing happened.

If this is normal XJC behavior, is it possible to tweak it to generate code without this parameter, or with another value than `String`?

Note that everything is working fine, but I would like to understand.
Also I'm using Enunciate to document my API and it seems to be confused by this `type` thing (but this is probably a bug in Enunciate).

---

I'm using JAXB RI 2.2.6, and here are some pieces of code, to illustrate my question:

**bindings.xjb**

```xml
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0" ...>
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <jaxb:javaType
                name="java.lang.Integer"
                xmlType="xs:integer"
                parseMethod="..."
                printMethod="..." />
        </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

**Field definition in the XSD**

```xml
<xs:complexType name="MyType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="myField" type="xs:integer" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

**Generated Java field**

```java
@XmlElement(namespace = "...", required = true, type = String.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1.class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "integer")
protected Integer myField;
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but for the people still looking for an answer:
using type `xs:int` instead of `xs:integer` will create a normal java int instead of the `Biginteger`.

Comment: The problem with int is that it does not support being null, Integer does.

Comment: All true, but my question was not about the target java type, but about the generated `@XmlElement` annotation.
Also if I could change the XSD to use `xs:int` (which I can't, that's why I'm using an adapter), I suspect JAXB would generate an `int` **OR** an `Integer`, depending of the nullability of the field.

Comment: Specifying `type="int"` yields an `int`, specifying `minOccurs=0` with `type="int"`yields an `Integer`.

Comment: @EricDuminil I found I had to use `nillable="true"` rather than `minOccurs=0`